# Sharing an ObjectDataProvider in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, objectdataprovider

I am trying to share an ObjectDataProvider resource between my main application and a user control. I define the odp in a separate resource dictionary file that is included in the app and the user control.

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AsymmetricFrameHolder" 
    ObjectType="{x:Type data:DataFrameAsymmetric}"/>
```

Then I try to access this in the main app as follows:

```
ObjectDataProvider odp = (ObjectDataProvider)Resources["AsymmetricFrameHolder"];
return (DataFrameAsymmetric)odp.ObjectInstance;
```

And bind it in the user control with:

```
<Grid Name="grid"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" 
   DataContext="{StaticResource AsymmetricFrameHolder}">
```

Then:

```
<TextBox  Name="TextBox_Length"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Length }"/>
```

This creates 2 instances of DataFrameAsymmetric. One in the main app and one in the user control.

How can I set the program so that a single shared instance is created?

Comment: Actually this code has helped me out a bunch!  I was wondering how to refresh a objectdataprovider.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can take a different route this problem can be solved easily. Convert your Class DataFrameAsymmetric in to **[Singleton class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx)** and at any place you want to use the instance of it use as bellow

```
<Grid Name="grid"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static data:DataFrameAsymmetric.Instance}}">
```

At any part of your code you will be able to access the instance by

```
DataFrameAsymmetric.Instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but a singleton wouldn't work here. I will need to make more than one instance of the class in the program.